# pro tools 9 odd freeze and crash

Tags: playback, troubleshooting, pro-tools-9

I'm working on 3 separate projects in pt9, not identical but similar in content. 2 of them work fine but 1 of them crashes after a second of playing back. This seems to happen anywhere in the edit (if I click on playback elsewhere for example).

Anyone encountered this? quite hard to find the fault through google.

Thanks

Oh forgot to add that I open up an autosave backup and it works... until I save the project again and it fails. :(

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Shaun's good advice, you may also have a corrupted fade or file (I've seen all sorts). If clearing Prefs etc. doesn't work try these:

First, try deleting the Fade Files for the session... PT will rebuild them. Corrupted Fade Files can cause all sorts of weirdness.

Second, try a "Save Session Copy In" with all audio files. If there's a weird filename (which can happen and wreak all sorts of havoc) it will tell you and rename the file properly.

Lastly, create a new session. Import tracks from the old session one at a time. Play your timeline. If it crashes right after importing a specific track, then something in that track is off, and it will be easier to find -either media or a specific plug-in could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

when in doubt: trash all preferences, repair disk permissions and restart.

another trick you can try is to make all tracks "inactive" (note that this is not a "voice" selection idea, you do this by right-clicking a track or through the track menu), play back for 10-15 seconds, then reactivate the tracks. 9 can encounter a memory caching problem, and this will sometimes clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you on? I started to have a lot of crashes too when i updated to 9.05
Previous versions worked much better.

Comment: I did too.  I ended up with going back to 9.02 and staying there.

Answer (score 0):

also tries to delete the folders "digidesign database"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for feedback, no luck with databse deleting sadly, I'm on an early version of PT9.

I get a DAE ERROR too... I suspect it could be fades and will try that, at present I'm just working of the most previous back up.

Thanks again